# CanI still use HTTP instead HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, https

I have an app using HTTPS. I have some problems in IE because is asking users different things. There are different popups depending which version of IE the user has, and the app doesn't work if user do not click ok.

Is possible to still use HTTP? HTTP is a bad experience for user and for my app because requires additional popups and most of users do not know what HTTPS is (users != IT engineers)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see browser warnings when you load a content (image, script, css) from HTTP URI within an HTTPS page.
Load image, script, css etc. with an HTTPS URI/URL like:

```
<img src="https://yoursite.com/images/img.png" />
```

Or use relative URI like:

```
<img src="images/img.png" />
```

You must have to provide an HTTPS URI in your app settings, however you can still use HTTP URI for user end, but user with "Enabled secure browsing" on in their FB security settings will be redirected to to your given HTTPS URI.

So in my opinion use HTTPS for all.